# Data binding for BaseAdapter in android

Tags: android, data-binding, baseadapter

I couldn't find any information about how can I use data binding in BaseAdapter. Do you have any information about creating data binding instance? Data binding, I mean the alternative way of findViewById

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should add like that in build.gradle(app)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ZC3.png)

and then this picture may help you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBB3G.png)

Comment: I added already the dependency in the Gradle. Your solution based on RecyclerView.Adapter but my question was to add data binding in BaseAdapter

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)